# Using Cursor as a base to build an Iterator

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm planning to build an `Iterator` based on an `Cursor` I'll be getting as a result of database queries:

```
  @Override public Iterator<Title> iterator() {
    final Cursor cursor = /* Gets a Cursor of Titles from DB */;
    final Iterator<Title> iterator = new Iterator<Title>() {
      @Override public boolean hasNext() {
        return !cursor.isLast();
      }

      @Override public Title next() {
        cursor.moveToNext();

        return new CursorTitle(cursor);
      }

      @Override public void remove() {
        try {
          removeTitle(new CursorTitle(cursor));
        } catch (TitleNotFoundException e) {
          throw new AssertionError();
        }
      }
    };

    cursor.close();

    return iterator;
  }
```

But I've been getting exceptions because I'm basically trying to get data from a closed `Cursor`.

I know I'm asking something that is rather weird here; but I'm just curious. Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

*p.s., I might get away by not closing the `Cursor` and call it a day. But come on, that'd be idiotic.*

Comment: You may want to add a new method in your Iterator to wrap the `cursor.close()`. And figure out when you want to call close on the cursor.

Comment: Hmm.. That's actually a good idea! I'll try to experiment with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.close();` is running in your `iterator`,so once this iterator starts,the cursor will close,that's why your error exists,so just remove it other methods that you're sure it will be executed once you don't need it remains opening state anymore.

Comment: Constructor.. where? I don't recall giving out any of my constructor code in this question.

Comment: sorry,not constructor,it's `iterator ` method.